# Javascript not assigning new value to variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb

OK I am doing this in a node.js file. I have a function that is suppose to search for a user in mongodb, based off a certain fields. It is suppose to capture their account value and then pass it on for further evaluation. However the account variable remains null. It looks like this:

```
function checkIfUserExist (name, lobby, socket) {
    var account_ID = null;
    Clients.findOne({ user_name_perm: name }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Cannot find user with perm name: checkIfUserNameExist");
        } else {
            if (result == null) {
                ...} else {
                console.log("User perm name is: " + result.user_name_perm);
                console.log("result.account_ID: " + result.account_ID);
                account_ID = result.account_ID;
            }
        }
    });
    console.log("Account ID: " + account_ID);


    if (!account_ID == null) {...} else {
        console.log("User doesn't exist");
    }               
}
```

The log portion looks like this:

```
Account ID: null
User doesn't exist
User perm name is: Peter
result.account_ID: 15555555555
```

This is very confusing to me, it seems like the function is evaluating everything but the database look up first, which makes account_ID null for evaluation purposes, then it goes into the database and makes the new evaluation after the fact, maybe, why is it doing this?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findOne` runs asynchronously, so if you want to use its result you have to employ a synchronization mechanism such as passing continuations or using callbacks.

### Continuation passing

```
function checkIfUserExist (name, lobby, socket, callback) {
    var account_ID = null;
    Clients.findOne({ user_name_perm: name }, function (err, result) {
        // snip
        console.log("Account ID:", account_ID);

        if (!account_ID == null) {
            callback(null, result);
        } else {
            console.log("User doesn't exist");
            callback(new Error);
        }  
    });                 
}
```

Then you have to call `checkIfUserExist` with a new argument -- a function that is called when the query completes and you know the result.

### Promises

The mongo client you are using likely returns promises from asynchronous methods as well.

```
function checkIfUserExist (name, lobby, socket) {
    var account_ID = null;
    return Clients.findOne({ user_name_perm: name })
      .then(function (result) {
          console.log("Account ID:", result.account_ID);
          return result;
      }).catch(function (err) {
          // handle error
      });
}
```

Now you can chain `.then` to the return value of `checkIfUserExist`. You still have to pass a callback to the `.then` method though.  May look like:

```
checkIfUserExist(name, lobby, socket).then(function (result) {
    response.status(200).json(result);
}).catch(function (err) {
    response.status(500).end(err.message);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out, ended up altering my way of thinking when dealing with JS. Basically anywhere I wanted to assign I needed to callback, I suppose I could also just return there as well. TY

Answer (score 0):

This is due to asynchrony

```
function checkIfUserExist (name, lobby, socket) {
    var account_ID = null;
    Clients.findOne({ user_name_perm: name }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Cannot find user with perm name: checkIfUserNameExist");
        } else {
            if (result == null) {
                ...} else {
                console.log("User perm name is: " + result.user_name_perm);
                console.log("result.account_ID: " + result.account_ID);
                account_ID = result.account_ID;
                console.log("Account ID: " + account_ID);

            }
        }
    });


    if (!account_ID == null) {...} else {
        console.log("User doesn't exist");
    }               
}
```

What is happening is that the callback in findOne is executed later than the console.log... you have to deal with asynchrony all time, I recommend https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: You're basically right, but the code is wrong. The account_ID will be filled probably after the `if (!account_ID == null) {...} else {` is executed. You need to do everything within the callback function of the `findOne` method.